# using the finance gem in a rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I am trying to use the "finance" gem for a rails project. I have successfully installed the gem by editing my Gemfile and using "bundle install". I have included the line:

application_controller.rb

```
include Finance
```

This allows me access to the finance gem functions in controllers. But, something wonky is going on with my numbers. If you go to the following link you can see a simple example of how to create a Rate object and use it to find amortization:

http://rubydoc.info/gems/finance/1.1.2/frames

But, in a controller, when I try to set a Rate object to a variable using the code provided:

```
@rate = Rate.new(0.0425, :apr, :duration => 30.years)
```

...this throws the error "wrong argument type Flt::DecNum (expected scalar Numeric)"

What is going on is the value "0.0425" that I'm passing into Rate is apparently a Float/DecNum but it's expecting a Numeric object. If I use the code below to cast the number to a Numeric type, the error is gone but the Rate object created isn't really working properly:

```
@rate = Rate.new(0.0425.to_c, :apr, :duration => 30.years)
```

All in all I just want to be able to use the finance gem in controllers and/or helpers but there seems to be some errors generated because the numbers I'm passing are of the wrong type. Can anyone offer any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this question got no attention I wanted to post my solution in case others run across this.

So, I ended up not using this gem and just writing the methods myself. The reason being that this gem was written specifically for Ruby, not for Rails. Other users got the same error as I did and the only resolution was to hack actual code in the gem if you were using this on a Rails site.

So, the solution, at least for now would be to not use this gem for Rails, only for purely Ruby. The author I believe states this plainly but something I overlooked.

Thanks!

Comment: there is actually some recent discussion on this issue on the github page. so, possibly a fix on the horizon for those using Rails:  https://github.com/wkranec/finance/issues/9#issuecomment-9894030